# there is a significant different result between qqplot and lillie,test for normality test

Tags: r, normality-assumption

In R, when I test the normality of Decathlon dataset, the results of `qqplot` and `lillie.test` are very different. The size of the sample is about 7800. Here is my code and performance:

```
library("GDAdata")
data(Decathlon, package = "GDAdata")
lillie.test(Decathlon$P100m)
qqnorm(Decathlon$P100m)
qqline(Decathlon$P100m,col='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Decathlon$P100m has over 7,000 points. When N is large, Lilliefors (or any test) will give significant results for even trivial deviations from normality.

Second, why are you testing the normality of the 100 meter race times?

Comment: Thx u for your answer. I want to analyse whether there is a significant difference between years' athletes in 100m performance by ANOVA.So I need to test the normality firstly. Can I follow the results of qqplot?

Comment: No, you don't need to test the normality, at least not of the data. ANOVA does not assume normality of the data, only the residuals. 

I would go with the plot.

But any good software will give you tools for doing this, you shouldn't need to code it yourself.

Comment: got it.Thx u so mush